# Can we automate AWS SCT data extraction agents?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dms

Planning a data migration from on-premise to aws RDS.
Do we need to run  the AWS SCT data extraction agents manually everyday. Is there any method that allows to automate/schedule please?
Do we need to run the AWS DMS Task manually everyday. Is there any method that allows to automate/schedule please?

Manually running. Looking to schedule it.

Comment: Are you looking for just one time migration ? or looking for continuous replication as well ?

Comment: Hi Manish, First of all, thanks for your response. Yes, one-time and then continuous as well thereafter with the CDC option.

Comment: The Full load plus CDC task option will take care of the initial migration and on going replication there after. Running AWS SCT is completely optional. There is no need to run AWS SCT daily unless your source on-premise DB schema changes daily.